# How to change False to True using the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React.js. And I decided to make such an application. I would like to know how to change False to True using the buttons in action. You can explain or you can an example.  Tried to change it, but nothing changed. Thank you in advance!

`

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleToggleComplete = this.handleToggleComplete.bind(this);
  }



  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.length) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      id: this.state.items.length + 1,
      text: this.state.text,
      date: moment().format('l'),
      completed: 'false',
    }
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.concat(newItem),
      text: '',
    }));
  }


  handleToggleComplete() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      completed: !this.state.completed
    }))
  }    
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
            <tr className="hr">
              <td className="col1">{item.id}</td>
              <td className="col2">{item.text}</td>
              <td className="col3">{item.date}</td>
              <td className="col4">{item.completed}</td>
              <td className="col5"><button onClick={item.handleToggleComplete} className="btn btn-xs btn-success img-circle">&#x2713;</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </table>

    );
  }
}
```

`

[image]

Comment: You need to add code so can people help you to solve. Adding a picture is not helpful.

Comment: This screenshot isn't that helpful, please post your code

Comment: @bdbdbd I added the code

Comment: @Jalal I added the code

Answer (score 0):

I can not give you the solution (no code provided) so i will give you a hint.

Let's imagine  your state looks like this:

```
state = {
  completed: false
}
```

Your button can do such a thing:

```
button onClick={this.setState{(completed: !this.state.completed)}}
```

And in your table you can display the value like this:

```
{this.state.completed}
```

Maybe try to implement something similar in your code :)

Comment: If you want to have a feature of marking each item as "completed", you need to store each task as an object like item = {text:someInputValue, completed: false}. Clicking on each item should change the object's "completed" flag to "!item.completed" so it would change from false to true